# Android 4.4 and above can not receive boot broadcast

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

1、Limiting application installation location

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

2、Add boot broadcast permission

3、Registered broadcast

```
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

4、Receive broadcast print log and start service

```
public class MyBootBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //
        String action = intent.getAction();

        Log.e("TAG", isOrderedBroadcast() + "action:" + action);

        Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);

        context.startService(service);
      ｝
｝
```

Above for the realization of the code
But android 4.4 and more than the phone after the start of the broadcast, the following can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried on 5.1, it can receive BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast.
Think you need to remove this: android.intent.category.HOME.